# How do I execute an H2 stored procedure with Spring Data JPA & Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa, h2

I want to execute a simple H2 database stored procedure using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate.

Stored procedure class:

```
public class H2StoredProcedures {
    public static String stringIn(final String inValue) {
        log.info("stringIn: '{}'", inValue);
        return inValue + "_result";
    }
}
```

Stored procedure alias:

```
DROP ALIAS IF EXISTS STRING_IN;
CREATE ALIAS STRING_IN FOR "H2StoredProcedures.stringIn";
```

Executing in H2 console works as expected:

```
CALL STRING_IN('fooIn');
PUBLIC.STRING_IN('fooIn')  
fooIn_result
(1 row, 1 ms)
```

Spring Data JPA Repository Class:

```
@Procedure("STRING_IN")
String stringIn(@Param("inValue") final String inValue);
```

Repository Test:

```
@Test
public void testStringIn() throws Exception {
    assertEquals("fooIn_result", this.testRepository.stringIn("fooIn"));
}
```

Results in the following output:

```
2015-08-31 14:52:38,117 WARN  [main]: HHH000456: Named parameters are used for a callable statement, but database metadata indicates named parameters are not supported. [logger=org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl, mdc={}]
Hibernate: {call STRING_IN(?,?)}
2015-08-31 14:52:38,119 INFO  [main]: AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean 'adminDataSource1': getConnection ( null )... [logger=com.atomikos.jdbc.nonxa.AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean, mdc={}]
2015-08-31 14:52:38,128 WARN  [main]: Error delegating 'prepareCall' call [logger=com.atomikos.jdbc.JdbcConnectionProxyHelper, mdc={}]
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Method "STRING_IN (H2StoredProcedures, parameter count: 2)" not found; SQL statement:
 call STRING_IN(?,?)  [90087-187]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.engine.FunctionAlias.findJavaMethod(FunctionAlias.java:272)
    at org.h2.expression.JavaFunction.<init>(JavaFunction.java:32)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readJavaFunction(Parser.java:2364)
    [...]
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:159)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:622)
    at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.prepare(CommandRemote.java:68)
    at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.<init>(CommandRemote.java:45)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.prepareCommand(SessionRemote.java:492)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1189)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:72)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcCallableStatement.<init>(JdbcCallableStatement.java:52)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCall(JdbcConnection.java:899)
    [...]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.prepareCall(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:407)
    at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.outputs(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:234)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ProcedureExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:299)
    [...]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    [...]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.stringIn(Unknown Source)
    at TestRepositoryTest.testStringIn(TestRepositoryTest.java:227)
    [...]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
2015-08-31 14:52:38,131 WARN  [main]: SQL Error: 90087, SQLState: 90087 [logger=org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper, mdc={}]
2015-08-31 14:52:38,131 ERROR [main]: Method "STRING_IN (H2StoredProcedures, parameter count: 2)" not found; SQL statement:
 call STRING_IN(?,?)  [90087-187] [logger=org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper, mdc={}]
```

The same code against an MS SQL Server database with the following stored procedure works as expected:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE STRING_IN
    @InValue SYSNAME,
    @OutValue NVARCHAR(255) OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @OutValue = @InValue + '_result';
    RETURN;
END;
```

It seems like there is a bug in either the org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery#createStoredProcedure() or more likely Hibernates org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl#registerStoredProcedureParameter(String, Class, ParameterMode) which should know about the dialect.

I tried using @NamedStoredProcedureQuery and basically every annotation combination and I get essentially the same error about not finding a procedure with 2 parameters.

I also tried adding a version with an in/out parameter to the H2StoredProcedures:

```
public static void stringInOut(final String inValue, String outValue) {
    log.info("stringInOut: '{}'", inValue);
    outValue = inValue + "_result";
}
```

If I set up the in/out repository method with a String return type:

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "STRING_IN_OUT")
String stringInOut(@Param("inValue") final String inValue, @Param("outValue") String outValue);
```

I get a third parameter not found:

```
2015-08-31 15:19:15,517 ERROR [main]: Method "STRING_IN_OUT (H2StoredProcedures, parameter count: 3)" not found; SQL statement:
 call STRING_IN_OUT(?,?,?)  [90087-187] [logger=org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper, mdc={}]
```

If I set up the in/out repository method with a void return type:

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "STRING_IN_OUT")
void stringInOut(@Param("inValue") final String inValue, @Param("outValue") String outValue);
```

I get a error presumably try to map the result to void:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 0
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:653)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.JdbcResultMetadata.getHibernateType(JdbcResultMetadata.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(ScalarResultColumnProcessor.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl$CustomLoaderExtension.processResultSet(OutputsImpl.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.extractResults(OutputsImpl.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.extractCurrentResults(OutputsImpl.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.access$100(OutputsImpl.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl$CurrentReturnState.buildOutput(OutputsImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl$CurrentReturnState.getOutput(OutputsImpl.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.getCurrent(OutputsImpl.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:234)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ProcedureExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:299)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:371)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: so does a "H2 stored procedure" work when you use JDBC CallableStatement ? If so then it would work with JPA 2.1 StoredProcedureQuery. The SQLServer case clearly does because it is a real stored procedure. Many other RDBMS don't support such procedures in a way that is executable from JDBC

Answer (score 7):

I did some debugging and the short answer is that Hibernate JPA (at least 5.0.0 and below) does not support stored procedures for H2Dialect.

The H2Dialect inherits Dialect.getCallableStatementSupport() which returns StandardCallableStatementSupport.NO_REF_CURSOR_INSTANCE. The standard callable statement support does not properly handle the H2 "out" parameter which is a Java return value and not a statement parameter. I tried extending the H2Dialect and StandardCallableStatementSupport classes to create versions that support H2 callable statements. I then ran into issues in the org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl#buildOutputs method. This method implements it's own statement preparation instead of using the CallableStatementSupport#registerParameters method. There doesn't appear to be a clean way to extend ProcedureCallImpl or buildOutputs and the many todo's, including "TOTAL PROOF-OF-CONCEPT!!!!!", don't give me much confidence. I tried a modified version of the class to see if not including the output parameter in the statement would even work. I found that though it called the procedure it then didn't know how to process the result.

Comment: Still doesn't work with Spring 3 (Hibernate 6)